# How can I target elements whose classes don't contain the ID of this element?

Tags: jquery

Specifically, I want to say: *for elements whose class value doesn't contain this element's ID value, execute this function*.

For example, clicking `#foo` will execute `fadeOut()` on the list items whose classes don't contain `.foo` in the following HTML:

```
<button id="foo">foo</button>
<button id="bar">bar</button>
<button id="baz">baz</button>
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Lorem</li>
    <li class="foo bar">Ipsum</li>
    <li class="baz">Dolor</li>
</ul>
```

So upon clicking `#foo`, the last list item should disappear, since the first two both contain the `.foo` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('li:not(.'+this.id+')').fadeOut();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/PM9gw/)

Comment: Wonderful! This is the lightweight solution I was looking for! But now this beckons the question... how do I target the elements whose classes DO contain the button's ID? Sorry I'm extremely new at jQ/JS.

Comment: @Chris just remove the `:not()`, `$('li.'+this.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the buttons somehow so you can attach your event. Then you will need to extract the id and select those that do NOT contain that class. Here is an example using the `not` method:

```
 $(':button').click(function(){
  $('li').not('.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeOut(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ureyes84/Fr7dm/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('li').not('.foo').fadeOut();
});​
```

see:

http://jsfiddle.net/dSSza/

Comment: Thanks for your response! This was my original approach, but it's not exactly the most efficient because I'd have to repeat similar code for the other buttons.